# Does the alternating sum of primes converge?

Tags: number-theory

> Does the alternating series of primes $A(p) = 2-3+5-7+11-13+\cdots$ converge?

I was just thinking about this question, and I first thought it most likely doesn't converge since the prime gaps become so large and different as you get larger. But if it doesn't converge, how would one go about proving that it doesn't converge?

Comment: I think that this series is $<\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}-1$, hence diverges (i.e., every pair sums up to $-1$ or less).

Comment: Let $s_n$ be the alternating sum of the first $n$ primes.  Then $s_{n+2}$ < $s_n$ - 1.  Therefore $s_n$ diverges.

Comment: I think that gauss had found out the distribution if prime numbers between 0-100,100-1000 you can see that

Comment: It clearly diverges because the terms don't go to zero.

Comment: Euler-summation seems to be unable to assign a finite value to it (which I fid expremely surprising, because it can even provide a value for the divergent alternating geometric series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem: If $\sum a_i$ converges, then $\lim_{i\to\infty}|a_i|=0$

Thus we see that $A(p)$ doesn't converge, because the limit diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try using the limit test.